# How to set Redux Reducer's initial state based on AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, redux, state

Using Redux, I want one of my reducers initial state to be based on an AJAX call. Basically, I am using AJAX to get some data, and then putting it into the state of the Reducer. However, because of the AJAX call, the reducer is initialized with the initial state before the AJAX call is complete. How would you go about making reducer wait until the AJAX call is complete before setting the initial state?

## STORE

```
export default () => {
  const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      settings: settingsReducer,
    })
  );
  return store;
}
```

## REDUCER

```
var settingsDefaultState;

$.ajax({
  url: 'view/content/settings.xml',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(xml) {
    //DOING SOME STUFF WITH THE XML FILE HERE
    settingsDefaultState = {
      test: "HELLO WORLD"
    }
  },
  complete: function() {
    console.log("Settings Loaded...");
  }
});


export default (state, action) => {
  var tempState = {...state};
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return tempState;
  }
}
```

Comment: try with fectch() or async function before export :)

Comment: I don't think you can make the reducer wait until the AJAX call is complete, but you could implement a pattern in which the reducer is synchronously initialized with an "initializationState" property that can be used to track the state of the asynchronous initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you initialize your state as a `loading` state. That way you can give feedback to the user that something is happening. Then when the ajax call returns a response you trigger an action that will set your state to the desired next state.